# Manually create the same dataframe returned from fromJSON function

Tags: r, dataframe, jsonlite

I have a JSON string which returns a dataframe using jsonlite package.

```
 library(jsonlite)
 d  <- fromJSON('[{"x":"A","value":100},{"x":"B","value":100},{"x":["A","B"],"value":20}]' )
```

it gives me

```
     x value
1    A   100
2    B   100
3 A, B    20
```

But I want to re-create the same dataframe manually. Class of column *x* is a list.

My attempt is as follows:

```
   data.frame(x = c("A","B",list(c("A","B"))),value = c(100,100,20))
```

This gives me an error of *differing no. of rows*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can wrap with `I` on the `list` in `base R`

```
d1 <- data.frame(x = I(list("A", "B", c("A", "B"))), value = c(100, 100, 20))
d1
#      x value
#1    A   100
#2    B   100
#3 A, B    20
```

It would add an `attribute` for "AsIs",

```
attr(d1$x, "class")
#[1] "AsIs"
```

but it is the same data by ignoring the attributes

```
all.equal(d1, d, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or if we assign the attribute to NULL, it would be the same

```
attr(d1$x, "class") <- NULL
all.equal(d1, d)
#[1] TRUE
```

and if we use a `tibble`, it is more direct`

```
library(tibble)
tibble(x = list("A", "B", c("A", "B")), value = c(100, 100, 20))
```